# Load local SWF in AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, air, flex3

I want to be able to load a local SWFs in an AIR desktop application. The SWF files are located outside of the application itself on the user's hard drive.

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteHandler);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgressHandler);
loader.load(new URLRequest("/Users/Oliver/Documents/sample.swf"));
```

The file does exist. I can test its existence using the following in Unix:

`$ ls /Users/Oliver/Documents/sample.swf`

However, the application is throwing the error:

`Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2035: URL Not Found.`

If I attempt to load the same file from a web location (e.g. `http://127.0.0.1/sample.swf`), the load succeeds.

I understood that AIR could load both local and remote files. Is this not the case? Ironically, elsewhere in my application I am reading, writing and deleting arbitrary files from the local file system without issue. But I cannot load them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue is with your path. Try using the File class to get a path to your swf.

```
var f:File = File.documentsDirectory
f = f.resolvePath("sample.swf");
/* ----- */

loader.load(new URLRequest(f.url));
```

Comment: That's the trick! Thanks! It seems the loader needs to use the file:// URI scheme (or http:// for remote files). I've edited your code as it had a small error in it.

Comment: Hard coding the user account Oliver will cause this application to only work on your computer